# Android Studio - cant mark and delete

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I dont know whart I have done, but my "text cursor", does not work anymore.
I cant type anything and when I try, I just went right or left, but no typing...

[image]

Comment: try pressing `insert` key on your keyboard and see if it is fixed

Comment: Thanks, I have tried and it work a few minute.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. I have disable the Plugin called IdeaVim?

Comment: Hi! We're trying to investigate the problem when the users install the IdeaVim plugin without knowing how to work with it. Do you remember how have you installed this plugin?